# Need to create a void Intersect function

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

a function that takes in two array list and mutates the first one to only contain common elements

I tried this code but it fails

```
<T> void intersect (ArrayList <T> a1,ArrayList <T> a2 ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
      T element = a1.get(i);
      for(int j = 0; j < a1.size(); j++) {
        T elem = a2.get(j);
        if (element.equals(elem)) {

        }
      }
```

Comment: Why not just use `retainAll()`?

Comment: hey cannot use it because its out of bounds for this HW

Comment: Well right now you're not doing anything if the elements are equal. You just have an empty `if`

Comment: because I am not sure what to do

Comment: if I do an add there will be duplicates

Comment: Then maybe you don't need to add. What other way could you do this?

Comment: if `List` contains custom object `equals` will fail until you override `equals()` method

Comment: I thought maybe I could just write j++

Comment: yes. I will need Hashcode

Comment: Well right now you are checking to see if they are equal, but if you add it, that will do the opposite of what you want. Perhaps if you inverted your logic?

Comment: how do I override equals() method?

Comment: how do I remove it without using iterators?

Comment: Why can you not use iterators?

Comment: If you use a for-loop to go over an arraylist and want to remove elements I would say that you start at the end of the arraylist and go back to the beginning.